# Feynman 20-4: Question regarding centrifugal force and rotation in three dimensions

Tags: forces, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, torque, centrifugal-force

[image]

For full reference, refer to https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_20.html#Ch20-SUM

Here's the quote that I think is relevant to the question:

'Consider a wheel that is fastened onto a shaft in a lopsided fashion, but with the axis through the center of gravity, to be sure (Fig. 20–6). When we spin the wheel around the axis, anybody knows that there will be shaking at the bearings because of the lopsided way we have it mounted. Qualitatively, we know that in the rotating system there is centrifugal force acting on the wheel, trying to throw its mass as far as possible from the axis. This tends to line up the plane of the wheel so that it is perpendicular to the axis. To resist this tendency, a torque is exerted by the bearings.'

---

My question:

Why does centrifugal force 'tend' to make the plane of the rotating wheel perpendicular to the axis? In what scenario would there be no torque resisting this 'tendency'?

---

From how I am interpreting it, I can only visualize the friction between the wheel and the shaft inconsistently distributed due to the angle of the wheel. And in return, the wheel corrects the inefficiency in its rotation such that the wheel is perpendicular to the axis. I have also studied the previous sub-chapter 20-3 on gyroscope, but I failed to see any resemblance.

Comment: Anyone know the answer to this?